# Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, session

I'm trying to create a REST service using spring and JackSon JSON.

My DAOImpl:

```
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Users findByUserName(String username) {

        Users user = new Users();
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            if (!username.isEmpty() && username != null) {
                List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
                users = session.createQuery("from Users where username=?")
                        .setParameter(0, username)
                        .list();

                if (!users.isEmpty()) {
                    user = users.get(0);
                }

                transaction.commit();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {

            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

My Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/userbyname/{username}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Users findByUserName(@PathVariable("username") String username) {

        return userDao.findByUserName(username);
    }
```

And I'm getting this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy -
>   no Session (through reference chain:
>   com.spring.example.entities.Users["roles"]->com.enclaveit.brea.entities.Roles_$$_jvstd4_2["role"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain:
>   com.enclaveit.brea.entities.Users["roles"]->com.enclaveit.brea.entities.Roles_$$_jvstd4_2["role"])

As I understand because the session is closed in DAOImpl class so in the controller the session is no more, is it correct? When I try to comment the code line `session.close();` then the web work fine, I can receive the Json. But it is dangerous when a session couldn't close, right?

Looking for best solution.

NOTE: If you need more information please tell me.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Hibernate config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- MySQL data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.116:3306/brea" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="brea@123" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="-1"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- If request parameter "targetUrl" is existed, then forward to this url --> 
    <!-- For update login form -->
    <bean id="savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="targetUrl" />
     </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>orm/Roles.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>orm/Users.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>orm/UsersInfo.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                           org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                        </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.enclaveit.brea.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" 
                class="com.enclaveit.brea.services.MyUserDetailsService">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
        expression="execution(* com.enclaveit.brea.services.*Service.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

Error log:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.spring.example.entities.Users["roles"]->com.spring.example.entities.Roles_$$_jvstdf1_2["role"])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:184)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:605)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:241)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    com.spring.example.entities.Roles_$$_jvstdf1_2.getRole(Roles_$$_jvstdf1_2.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:679)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:534)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:241)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:193)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: Use @Transactional and let spring handle the transaction

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: Don't handle transactions and sessions yourself. Use Spring to do it for you. Next either return everything you need to create the JSON response or use a `OpenSessionInViewFilter` to keep the session open until the request finishes processing.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the proxy annotation to the Entity class does the job.

```
@Entity @Table(name="Country") @Proxy(lazy = false) public class Country {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is to first remove the session and transaction handling code from your service and simply replace it with `@Transactional` in your code (and `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your configuration.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly="true")
public Users findByUserName(String username) {
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();      
    return (Users) session
                    .createQuery("from Users where username=?")
                    .setParameter(0, username)
                    .uniqueResult();
}
```

Also note that `session` should be scoped to the method NEVER store the `Session` as in instance variable. (Imagine what would happen if 10 current calls to `findByUserName` are made what would happen to the instance variable `session`).

In your configuration enable annotation driven transaction management. (Assuming you already have a `HibernateTransactionManager` definedn!).

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Next add an `OpenSessionInViewFilter` to your request handling chain (i.e. register the filter in your web.xml or initializer when using java config).

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <!-- Replace with hibernate3, hibernate4 or hibernate5 depending on the hibernate version one uses -->
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <!-- name of your DispatcherServlet -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Then you haven't configured the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` correctly OR haven't implemented the method correctly. Note the `getCurrentSession` and not `openSession`!. Or your hibernate configuration is wrong and not properly integrated with Springs Tx management. Add the hibernate configuration to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with Spring framework, make use of `declarative transaction` management instead of `programmatic transactions`.

I believe your `Users` entity has `role` property with lazy loading. Either you can change this to eager loading (not preferable) or in DAO method load the `role` information using getter `user.getRole()` before session close.

Comment: Is there any other choice to keep lazy loading?

Comment: Yes in DAO method load the role information using getter (something like user.getRole()) before session close.